# Applying ratio test to negative series then taking the absolute value of the limit

Tags: sequences-and-series

If I want to check the convergence of this series

$$\sum\frac{1-n}{n2^n}$$

can I use ratio test ? 
I know that the ratio test must be applied on positive series.
Is this correct to apply the ratio test then take the absolute value of the limit? 
$$\lim_{n->\infty}\frac{1-(n+1)}{(n+1)2^{n+1}}\frac{n2^n}{1-n}=\frac{1}{2}$$

hence the series converges.

Note :

I proved that the series converges also since the sum/difference of 2 convergent series converges.
$$\sum\frac{1}{n2^n}-\sum\frac{1}{2^n}$$

But I want to know whether applying the ratio test then taking the absolute value is correct.

Comment: the ratio test works just fine.  In fact, you do compute the absolute value of the ratios.

Comment: the ratio test tests for *absolute convergence*

Comment: So although the ratio here shows that the series converges and the series really converges, it is wrong to apply it here because some terms are negative .. So we never apply it for a series that has some terms that are not positive ? .. Thanks !

Comment: Dear MCS, it is RIGHT and CORRECT to apply the ratio test. It will give you absolute convergence of the series and hence regular convergence of the series as well.

Comment: What if the ratio test on a negative series like our series shows that the absolute series diverges ? and we want to test the series itself not the absolute series ?... Our series is not alternating series , so we can not check Leibniz conditions for convergence .. can we take the negative sign common factor , as following : - $\frac{n-1}{n2^n}$ , so if the absolute series diverges , then the original series diverges also since it is just the absolute series multiplied by -1 ????

Comment: @MCS See this : http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/RatioTest.aspx